# How do I create single volume deployment with minio-operator

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, minio, kubernetes-operator

I was able to create a single volume minio pod in the past but with new minio-operator, minimum number of volumes attached to each pod is 4.
https://github.com/minio/operator/blob/master/examples/tenant-tiny.yaml

Is there a way to create a single volume minio deployment with new operator?

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/minio/operator/blob/master/examples/kustomization/tenant-tiny/tenant.yaml

Have you tried to change to "volumesPerServer: 1" and deploy?